# Can I move my 'acf-json' folder from production to local

Tags: wordpress, git, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have been making edit to my ACF fields/groups on the production site as we were in the process of setting up a dev and staging site. This is now ready and the files from production have been copied over to staging and dev.

My question is do I have to sync all my ACF fields on my dev server or can I carry on working normally and push any changes to ACF field group to git Master branch where I can then pull from production?

If I sync the acf fields on my dev server, this would get stored in the dev database. Once this database is copied over to production, would this not cause any issues on production?

[image]

Comment: ACF has a built-in export tool that you can use to get your fields from production into your dev site (see WP Dashboard > Custom Fields > Tools). Or just copy your acf-json folder and paste it into the acf-folder on dev. Two suggestions: 1. Use git to keep track of changes between dev and production, and 2. Avoid making changes directly in production, use the development server instead, that's what it's for.

Comment: @cabrerahector thanks buddy for the clarification. When I copy over the acf-json folder to dev, it will say 'sync available'. Is that needed to be done on dev? There is a link to the image in my post

Comment: Yes, you need to "sync" your changes from production into dev. Same thing when you push changes made in dev into production. Otherwise your custom fields won't be updated.

Comment: @cabrerahector syncing it on dev would also update the database. If the dev database is going to be copied over to production, this will have the field groups stored there which I have heard is bad practice as the fields should be read from the json file and not the database